# How to get the third field from a .csv file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My file, abc.csv, contains:

```
a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j
```

My code is as follows; the for loop doesn't give me the desired output i.e c h

```
for line1 in open('abc.csv', 'r') :
    result = line1.split(",")[2]
    print result
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Dude, seriously... you've asked a variation of this question multiple times and have been told to use the `csv` module multiple times. Why don't you just go and do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I verified your code to be working perfectly fine. But in any case, you should prefer the `csv` module for parsing CSV files:

```
import csv

with open('abc.csv', 'rb') as f:  # note the 'b' flag--this is needed with CSV
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
        print row[2]
```